# Getting the width of a Dynamic TextView inside a Table Row

Tags: android, textview

I am stuck up here trying to **get the width of a TextView in a Table Row** after setting some random text to it. 
I am using the **getWidth()**, but it returns zero always. Is there a way to find out the width of a dynamically created TextView.

Here is my code.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    customer_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.customer_id);
    comapny_name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.compnay_name);
    line1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.line1);




    TableLayout tl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.linlay);
    TableRow tr1 =null;
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        tr1 = new TableRow(this);
    tr1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setText("data");
    textview.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    textview.setTextSize(30);


    TextView textview1 = new TextView(this);
    textview1.setText("data1");
    textview1.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    textview1.setTextSize(30);

    tr1.addView(textview);
    tr1.addView(textview1);
    tl.addView(tr1);

int width=textview.getWidth();
Log.i("Width",width+"");

}
```

Comment: based on the width of it I have to align its header(Title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok actually the layout is inflated but not yet drawn so in order to get width you will have to

```
@Override 
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{ 
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
     super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
     System.out.println("...111Height..."+textview.getMeasuredWidth()); 
}
```